# apache2.4 build not finding php5.3

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-12.04

I am setting up a test server before upgrading an elderly version of mediawiki on a production server. I am trying to duplicate what will be on the production server - apache2.4 and php5.3.

When I try to access any php file, the server displays it as text rather than running it.

This is all running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The apache package available is version 2.2, so I can't simply apt-get.

I have built apache 2.4 from source, and it correctly serves an index.html from my designated DocumentRoot.

In httpd.conf, I have added:

```
DocumentRoot = /var/www
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
<filesMatch>"\.php$:"
   SetHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
</filesMatch>
```

I have installed php5.3, and it is working - I can run phpinfo.php from a command line.

In /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini I have (error displays are for testing only):

```
engine = On
display_errors = On 
display_startup_errors = On 
doc_root = /var/www
```

I am not able to find a reference to a mod_php of any sort either in the httpd.conf or in the directory in which httpd is installed (/usr/local/apache2).

Some of the references on the web mention "modules-available" and "modules-enabled" but these appear to be a convenience added by Debian, and are not part of the apache source build.

What am I missing? I'm sure it's something simple.

Answer (score 1):

After searching and using packages from several repositories for both apache and php, and trying to build either or both from source, I determined that there did not seem to be a libphp5.so that was compatible with apache 2.4. In any case, I didn't find it.

I reconfigured everything to use php as cgi rather than as a module, and got things working that way, which was enough for my intended purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load php module in httpd.conf:

On my Linux Slackware I have this in /etc/httpd/mod_php.conf

```
LoadModule php5_module lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so

# Tell Apache to feed all *.php files through PHP.  If you'd like to
# parse PHP embedded in files with different extensions, comment out
# these lines and see the example below.
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

And in /etc/httpd/httpd.conf:

```
# php
Include /etc/httpd/mod_php.conf
```

Comment: I have no such module, and as I said, have not been able to find it via Google or the package installer for my distribution. My httpd.conf file has dozens of modules listed, but none for php. Perhaps this was a compile option I missed?

Comment: @mickeyf According to this: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/installing-php5-and-apache-on-ubuntu/, the module must be in libapache2-mod-php5

Comment: @mickeyf Plus http://pkgs.org/search/?keyword=apache+php5 this gave me a log of packages, including Ubuntu.

Comment: I found libapache2-mod-php5, installed it with apt-get, copied libphp5.so to the modules directory since that was not where apt-get put it, edited my httpd.conf, and got a "undefined symbol" error when I restarted apache. I'm a bit suspicious that it's libphp5.so when everything else is uniformly named mod_somethingor other.

Comment: @mickeyf On my system it's also libphp5.so, so this file is ok

Comment: @mickeyf look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080119/undefined-symbol-error-on-loading-a-module-in-apache-that-uses-libxml2, maybe, the order of commands is important - on my system mod_php.conf is included at the end of httpd.conf

Comment: Maybe? apache2.4.4, "PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 with Suhosin-Patch". I built apache from source, but php is from a repository.

Comment: I have no mod_php.conf anywhere. If it's only a few lines could you post it? Never mind, I found an example and all that it in my httpd.conf already.